# get last added id in first table and insert it in another table using java

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to insert the last added id of my `chapter` table to the `lesson` table.

Here is my code:

```
String Sql = "INSERT INTO lesson"
            +"(title, chapter_id, source)"
            +"VALUES(?,?,?)";
String getId = "SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM chapter";
rs = pst.executeQuery(getId);
int lastid = rs.getInt("id");
rs.close();
pst=conn.prepareStatement(Sql);
pst.setString(2,txt_lessonTitle.getText());
pst.setInt(3,lastid);
pst.setString(4,txt_lessonContent.getText());

pst.executeUpdate();
```

I got an error:

> Before start of result set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check whether there are some results

```
rs = pst.executeQuery(getId);
if (rs.next()) {
        int lastid = rs.getInt("id");
        rs.close();
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(Sql);
        pst.setString(2,txt_lessonTitle.getText());
        pst.setInt(3,lastid);
        pst.setString(4,txt_lessonContent.getText());

        pst.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: the correct statement is you need to move the cursor to first row as by defautl  a `ResultSet` cursor is initially positioned before the first row

Comment: to set index of params you should start from 1 not 2 this can cause an error :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int lastid;
rs.afterLast();
while (rs.previous()) {
    lastid = rs.getInt("id");
}
rs.close();

// other code statements can be here
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys!. .my error is here:

```
    pst.setString(2,txt_lessonTitle.getText());
    pst.setInt(3,lastid);
    pst.setString(4,txt_lessonContent.getText());
```

instead of using

```
    pst.setString(1,txt_lessonTitle.getText());
    pst.setInt(2,lastid);
    pst.setString(3,txt_lessonContent.getText());
```

thanks for your answer and suggestions it gives me the answer.